# Stylecop hide rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, stylecop

I need to skip the rule of using sort of stylecop. I had tried to put on class, namespace; to no avail.

[The document for the same topic (archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023173831/http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1210.html)

Any ideas on the right place to place this code?

Comment: Why not just sort the using, use something like Productivity tools for VS to help https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd

Comment: I have culture issue in sorting with 'v' and 'w' in English and Finnish language

Comment: In my case I prefer to order the using by "domain" (.Net libs, 3th party libs and than my company libs and projects) instead of the default (useless in my opinion) alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains how to use the [SuppressMessage (archived link)](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/Suppressions.html)

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "SA1210:UsingDirectivesMustBeOrderedAlphabeticallyByNamespace", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
    public class MyUndocumentedClass
    {
        public void MyUndocumentedMethod
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting on which element I have to put in the file

Comment: Not working, still getting error as : Error 3 SA1210 : CSharp.Ordering : Using directives must be sorted alphabetically by the namespaces.